# Using bash/tail/perl/alias for easy highlighting of different strings

Tags: perl, bash

I am developing a tomcat application and would like to be able to search for specific things and highlight it when viewing the log. I want something like an alias that takes a parameter (regex) as input and highlight the matching string.

So far, I've figured this works, but its not practical enough to have to change a small part of it for every time I want something new:

```
tail -n 100 -f /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.26/logs/catalina.out | perl -pe 's/null/\e[1;31m$&\e[0m/g'
```

This is what I thought would work:

```
logColor(){
  x="'s/"
  y="/\e[1;31m$&\e[0m/g'"
  tail -n 100 -f /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.26/logs/catalina.out | perl -pe $x$1$y
}
alias logC=logColor
```

I've tested that this prints out the two same lines:

```
logColorTest(){
  x="'s/"
  y="/\e[1;31m$&\e[0m/g'"
  echo $x$1$y
  echo "'s/null/\e[1;31m$&\e[0m/g'"
}
alias logCT=logColorTest
logCT null
```

So I am lost on why this does not work and would appreciate input from someone who knows how this works :)

Comment: Why don't you use `grep --color=auto`?

Comment: Problem with `grep` is that, you get only matching lines & other lines are filtered out. (That's what is `grep` supposed to do anyway.) Many times however, we need all the output, but with some particular strings highlighted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem with `grep` is that, you get only matching lines & other lines are filtered out. (That's what is `grep` supposed to do anyway.) Many times however, we need all the output, but with some particular strings highlighted.

I have this small bash function in my `.bashrc` for such requirement:

```
mark () 
{ 
    local searchExpr=${1/\//\\\/};
    sed "s/$searchExpr/"`echo -n -e "\e[91;1m"`'&'`echo -n -e "\e[0m"`'/gi' $2
}
```

Usage:

```
command | mark some_string # OR
mark some_string some_file
```

Rename to suitable function name if required.

NOTE: There is a great command called `highlight`. Hence I could not use that as my function name.

Comment: This is just what I need, and it works like a charm. Thank you! I'm still wondering what the problem was with my initial function though :)

Comment: Wow. Great.Work with regular expressions

Answer (score 5):

As @fedorqui pointed out, you can use `grep` to do this:

```
grep --colour 'null\|$'
```

This will match and highlight `null` or the end of a line, meaning all lines are shown.

Using the [`GREP_COLORS`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Environment-Variables.html) environment variable you can control how different parts are highlighted, e.g mark matched text in yellow:

```
export GREP_COLORS='ms=1;33'
```

Comment: It's a nice one, but anishsane's solution fits better with the way I was thinking. This might be usable if I want to customize the colours easier later on. Ill look into it, thanks!

Comment: I usually match `^` instead of `$` :  `grep --colour '^|null'` (I believe it "helps" a tiny bit as the regexp on each line has an immediate match with '^' and knows the whole line can be outputed, without having to first look until the end of line and then print the line it just parsed... not sure how it translate in reality but it's probably a little bit more efficient (memory wise too))